# In Rails, can I perform ActionMailer logic in a controller action after JS response?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, actionmailer

Whenever a model is created in my application, an email is sent out to several people. The response to the model creation is JS, so there is a slight delay in updating the page because first all the emails are being sent then the JS view logic kicks in (i.e. there is a noticeable lag between the time the Create button is pushed and when the page updates itself).

Is there a way I can set up my controller so that the emails are sent AFTER the view is finished updating?

Here is what my Controller action basically looks like:

```
def create
  @model = Model.new(params[:model])
  @model.save

  @followers.each do |f|
    ModelMailer.some_email(f).deliver
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DelayJob or other background worker to do this and the add `handle_asynchronously :deliver` to your mailer.

Comment: this seems pretty good. if I'm using Heroku and HireFire, do I need to specify something like `worker: rake jobs:work` in a Procfile to get it to work automatically?

Comment: You need to specify worker in Procfile. You have it in Heroku docs.

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted Hauleth's answer since that's the right way to handle sending mail.

Another option is to give the user feedback while the system is working. It's a UI design pattern that goes by various names like "loading" and "processing". In short: Set a message on the client before sending the request, then update that message with success or failure when the response is complete, which itself can be timed out so the message is temporary.

If the action is remote, aka ajax, then you should always apply this UI pattern.

If the action is rendering a whole new page, then it's useful when you know the response is likely to be slow, as in your case.